# How to pick SVG code from a page where we have multipule SVG in DIV tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, html5-canvas

I have a php page where i have 8 DIV tag under each DIV tags I'm rendering some SVG (Fusion or High charts) based graphs which is dynamic. I would like to pick a particular SVG code. Currently I'm using

```
svg = $('svg').parent().html();
```

but this code give me only parent SVG code. In case if i want to have 4th or 5th SVG code i'm unable to pick.

I really appreciate if someone can show me how to pass DIV ID or something to pick a particular SVG code on run-time

Comment: $("svg") gives you an array of elements (if there is more than one SVG tag), not just a single element. Access them using $("svg")[n] or $("svg").get(n).

Comment: @GJK - your comment looks like a decent answer to me, given the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to iterate through the array:

```
$('svg').map(views);

function views(index, node)
  {
  if (index === 0)
    {
    return $(node).get(0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can also use `$('svg').each(function(index){})` http://api.jquery.com/each/ The map function will return a new array which doesn't seem necessary here.